# Parameter 3 is not constant in call of system task $fwrite

Tags: cryptography, hardware, verilog, xilinx

I am using Xilinx ISE 10.1 to run some verilog code. In the code I want to write the register values of 3 registers in a file, cipher.txt. The following is the code snippet:

```
if (clk_count==528) begin
  f1 = $fopen("cipher.txt", "w");
  $fwrite(f1, "clk: %d", clk_count[11:0]);
  $fwrite(f1, "plain: %h",  plain[31:0]);
  $fwrite(f1, "cipher: %h",  cipher[31:0]);
  $fclose(f1);
end
```

At the end of execution, the contents of cipher.txt is found as:

```
clk: %dplain: %hcipher: %h
```

There is no other error encountered, but a warning comes up corresponding to the 3 fwrite's:

```
Parameter 3 is not constant in call of system task $fwrite.
Parameter 3 is not constant in call of system task $fwrite.
Parameter 3 is not constant in call of system task $fwrite.
```

The values of the registers clk_count and cipher change on every clock cycle (value of register plain remains constant throughout), and the values are written to cipher.txt when clk_count equals 528 (indicated by the if statement)

Can anybody provide some insight and/or help me get past this hurdle?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that ISE expects the arguments to `$fwrite` to be constant.  The warnings are referring to `clk_count[11:0], plain[31:0], and cipher[31:0]`, which are not constant. By definition they are changing each cycle so they are not known at compile time.  This also explains why they are not printing and you are seeing `%d` and `%h` in the output.

There is nothing to my knowledge in the Verilog spec that requires the arguments to `$fwrite` be constant. The same code works as expected with Cadence Incisive. My guess is that it's a limitation of ISE, so you may want to check with Xilinx.

Possible work-arounds:

1) Use `$swrite` to create a string with the proper formatting. Then write the string to the file.

2) Try using an intermediate variable in the calls to `$fwrite`.  Maybe the part-selects are throwing it off.  e.g.

```
integer foo;
foo = clk_count[11:0];
$fwrite(... , foo , ...);
```

Either of those *might* work, or not.

Out of curiosity, if you remove the part-selects, and try to print `clk_count` without the `[11:0]` , do you get the same warnings?

Comment: I am working on Xilinx 10.1. 

Neither work-around worked. 
1) $swrite created another register with formatted data, but $fwrite could not recognize even the new string register that was created.
2) tried intermediate integers too. didn't work either

part-selects are not responsible. checked; same warnings.

Comment: You could try using the free, open-source, terminal-based Icarus Verilog simulator (http://iverilog.icarus.com). Unless debugging designs with tons of signals, I actually prefer it to ModelSim. I've not been able to find any flaws in it, in fact, it helped me find flaws in both ModelSim and Xilinx ISE. Wholeheartedly recommended!

Comment: @Darhuuk Thanks for the suggestion. I have used Icarus Verilog for other projects. However, in this particular project I was working with an FPGA board for Simulating a reduced ISA.